# ThrowExceptionForHR + GetHRForLastWin32Error vs Win32Exception

Tags: c#, winapi, error-handling, pinvoke

Are these calls equivalent?

- `Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());`
- `throw new Win32Exception();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not equivalent.

- `Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error())` throws a COM exception. This could be `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` or an exception appropriate to the Win32 error code.
- `throw new Win32Exception()` throws a Win32 exception, `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception`.

Comment: Is it the only difference?

Comment: Well, it's a pretty fundamental difference! It's the case that these two exceptions wrap Win32 error codes. But that's where the similarities end.

Comment: Yes I meant an error code and its description but missed the detailes. Thanks.

Comment: Your first bullet is not very accurate, it throws the appropriate exception for the Windows error code.  Like 0x80070002 produces FileNotFoundException.  It only falls back to COMException when it can't make beans of the error code.